# python monty < python etc. why?

Tags: python

```
>>> "Monty" < "Python" 
True 
>>> "Z" < "a" 
True 
>>> "Monty" < "Montague" 
False
```

What's the rule about that? Is it the number of letters or what? 
thanks

Comment: What else did you expect?

Comment: The comparison is based on the ASCII values.

Comment: From my limited experience, it comes down to the letters within. In the first one, M is less than P in the ASCII "dictionary", so Monty is less than Python. Since Z is less than a, the bits that represent the string are again lower than the bits that represent the other. In the last one, the first four letters match, but the fifth compares y with a, and a obviously comes first and thus is less. Had the second one started with a lowercase m instead of a capital M, it would have returned true. Hope this helps, and if you want I can put it into an answer.

Comment: That's actually the whole question. Use the inequality operators to compare strings, e.g. 'Monty' < 'Python'. What happens when you do 'Z' < 'a'? Try pairs of strings which have a common prefix, e.g. 'Monty' < 'Montague'. Read up on "lexicographical sort" in order to understand what is going on here. Try comparing structured objects, e.g. ('Monty', 1) < ('Monty', 2). Does this behave as expected?

Answer (score 5):

It's lexicographically sorting. So "a" < "b".

If you use the `ord()` function, you can see "Z" has a lower value than "a"

```
>>> ord('Z')
90
>>> ord('a')
97
```

Comment: "lexical", not "alphabetic".

Comment: GJ beating me too it :) But it is really the ASCII codes that determine it, not the letters themselves. If it were the letters, then Z would be greater than a, not less.

Comment: what's ASCII ? And how do we know the values?

Comment: ASCII is a set of characters - pretty much the keys on a regular keyboard. There are other, wider sets like Unicode which cover wider language sets - mostly non-European languages

Answer (score 1):

Python strings, tuples and lists compare using [Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Example for tuples:

```
>>> (1,2) < (2,1)
True
>>> (1,2) < (1,2,-5)
True
```

Idea is simple: Compare element-by-element (for strings, char-by-char) until you have a difference or one is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Lexical sorting in the order that the letters are defined in ASCII range, so:

```
A ... Za ... z
```

That's why `'Z' < 'a'` is true.

When comparing two strings, each character is compared, if one is greater than the other, then the string is greater, if they are equal, move to the next character. If the end of one of the strings is reached, and the other one still has characters, the longest string is greater, otherwise, they're equal.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to confuse this order with the locale sensitive collation sequence.  For example:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.strcoll("Z","a")
-1
>>> "Z" < "a"
True
```

Probably what you expect, `locale.strcoll` returns -1 if the first string is less than the second, +1 if the first string is greater than the second (0 if they are equal).

But:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"")
'English_United Kingdom.1252'
>>> locale.strcoll("Z","a")
1
>>> "Z" < "a"
True
```

The locale can change the collation sequence, but (here) not with ordinary comparisons.  The English collation sequence goes aAbBcC...xXyYzZ (applies to other "en" locales).
For example:

```
>>> ml=["a","b","c","A","B","C"]
>>> sorted(ml)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c']
>>> sorted(ml,key=locale.strxfrm)
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C']
>>>
```

With non-ASCII characters, consider:

```
>>> locale.strcoll("é","f")
-1
>>> "é" < "f"
False
```